# iOS InApp purchases do not work in Production (okay in testflight)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight, production

I have 3 in-apps purchases available in the app.
On the release that is in production, I go to the screen to choose a subscription plan.
When I click the subscribe button, no bottom sheet opens up to confirm the price/subscription and ask the user to validate.

It is working fine in the testflight with the exact same build:

[image: Testflight ScreenShot when clicking subscribe button]

[image: Testflight ScreenShot after the purchase is confirmed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was coming from a wrong paramater passed to the validateIosReceipt function used in the code
The second paramater should be false (isTests) when in production otherwise the wrong receipt validation url is being called

But it means the same build cannot be used for TestFlight and for Production, as for TestFlight that parameter should be true, but in production should be false

Answer (score 1):

You could use this extension on Bundle to determine the correct value for your `isTests` parameter:

```
public extension Bundle {
    var isTests: Bool {
        #if DEBUG
            return true
        #else
            return self.appStoreReceiptURL?.lastPathComponent == "sandboxReceipt"
        #endif
    }
}
```

For debugging and TestFlight builds, this returns `true`, and for production builds `false`.